# Como capturar o resultado de um comando e armazenar em uma variável do MS-DOS em arquivo batch?

Tags: ms-dos

estou desenvolvendo um script batch para rodar no `MS-DOS` e preciso capturar a saída da execução de um aplicativo em uma variável, a qual poderá ser utilizada no decorrer da execução do arquivo`.bat`. A linha de comando que fornece o resultado desejado é:

```
C:\>youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T084eSHL6P8
```

O comando acima, quando executado no prompt do MS-DOS, fornece o seguinte resultado:

```
"Youtube-dl for windows - Baixando canais inteiros do youtube."
```

No meu arquivo`.bat` estou utilizando a seguinte linha para capturar e armazenar o resultado da execução do comando:

```
set var=(youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T084eSHL6P8)
```

O resultado não é o esperado, ou seja, exibe exatamente a string acima, porém, qual é a forma correta de atribuir o resultado do comando a uma variável?

Agradecendo antecipadamente qualquer ajuda,

atenciosamente

Augusto Cesar

Answer (score 3):

Peguei o exemplo daqui: [How to store the result of a command expression in a variable using bat scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427511/4730201)
E fiz um teste e funcionou:

```
set c="youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T084eSHL6P8"
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ( '%c%' ) do set xx=%i
echo %xx%
```

Comment: Funcionou! As modificações que efetuei foram as abaixo (podem servir para outros):

@echo off
cls
echo Aguarde enquanto o script captura o nome do video...
set c="youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T084eSHL6P8"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('%c%') do set xx=%%i
echo O nome do video eh: %xx%
pause