# Como capturar o resultado de um comando e armazenar em uma variável do MS-DOS?

Tags: cmd, checksum

Estou desenvolvendo um script e preciso verificar se um arquivo já foi convertido anteriormente. Resolvi criar uma base de dados salvando checksum do arquivo, e antes de converte o próximo arquivo eu verifico o checksum dele e comparado na base de dados se ele já foi convertido, se já tiver sido convertido eu descarto ele e passo para o próximo.

A questão é que quero fazer isso pelo CMD do Windows. Então estou usando o FCIV.EXE

Quando eu executo `fciv.exe a.mp4`

Me retorna

```
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
c6928bfc8e1313c057f57f17eaecd775 a.mp4
```

Gostaria de ter como resultado na variável apenas o checksum `c6928bfc8e1313c057f57f17eaecd775`

Gostaria de colocar o resultado em uma variável para continuar a usar no script, como fazer isso?

Se eu executar `fciv.exe a.mp4 -xml db.xml` é criado um banco de dados em xml, mas o que eu queria era criar uma variável com o resultado contendo o checksum do arquivo nesta variável criada para eu poder usar no decorrer do script.

Eu tentei algo do tipo `fciv.exe a.mp4 %checksum%`mas não tive resultado.

Também tentei utilizar um `for /f` com informações em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328329/como-capturar-o-resultado-de-um-comando-e-armazenar-em-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-do-ms-dos-em) feita aqui sobre o assunto mas não deu resultado.

```
cd /d "d:\videos"
for /f "delims=" %f in (' @"D:\videos\fciv.exe" a.mp4 ')
echo %f%
```

Quando executo este este .bat retorna:

```
d:\Videos>checksum.bat
'checksum.bat' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Ou existe alguma outra forma de pegar o checksum sem ser usando o fciv? que possa fazer o serviço de forma mais simples?

**Atualização:**

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
fciv.exe a.mp4 >> checksum.txt
for /f "usebackq skip=3 tokens=1 delims= " %%G in ("D:\videos\checksum.txt") DO echo %%G
del checksum.txt
```

`usebackq skip=3`
Vai pular as primeiras 3 linhas gravadas no .txt

```
delims= "
```

Vai utilizar o espaço para separar a string.

**Agora ficou faltando descobrir como executar o `fciv.exe a.mp4` dentro do `for /f` para não precisar passar pelo .txt**

Comment: Eu até tendei segui as orientações deste outro post mas não consegui resultado.

Comment: Acredito que o ideial aqui seria usar o token, assim poderia o checksum em uma variavel e nome do arquivo em outra variável, mas continuo recebendo erro. `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=; " %%G in (' @"D:\videos\fciv.exe" "a.mp4" ')`

Comment: O melhor resultado que cheguei até o momento foi passando o resultado do checksum para um arquivo .txt e lendo um arquivo .txt com o for.

`for /f "usebackq skip=3 tokens=1 delims= " %%G in ("D:\videos\t.txt") DO echo %%G`

A questão agora é, como executar o programa dentro deste for precisar passar para o .txt?

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off 

title <nul & title .\%~nx0
setlocal & cd /d "D:\videos" 

set "_hash=%cd%\mp4_hash.txt"
set "_ff=%ProgramFiles%\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

if not exist "%_hash%" >"%_hash%" (
     "%~dp0fciv.exe" "D:\videos" -type *.mp4 | find/v "/" 
    )else for %%i in (*.mp4)do call :^) "%%~i" "%_hash%" "%_ff%"

:^)
if "%~1" == "" endlocal && goto=:EOF
for /f tokens^=1-2 %%i in ('^^^< nul "%~dp0fciv.exe" "%~f1" ^|find/v "/"
')do echo=%%~i:"%%~j" & 2>nul %__AppDir__%findstr.exe %%~i "%~2">nul && exit/b 

"%~3" -hide_banner -v error -stats -i "%~1" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%~dpn1_tmp%~x1"

2>&1 move/y "%~dpn1_tmp%~x1" "%~1">nul && ("%~dp0fciv.exe" "%~f1" |find/v "/">>"%~2"
     echo=Arquivo: %~nx1 & echo\Convertido ^& MD5 adicionado na base "%~2" && exit/b
    ) || %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 5 | echo=Arquivo: "%~dpnx1" Falhou!... && exit/b
```

---

Presumindo:

**1.** Que o seu arquivo base sera criado numa primeira execução

**2.** Que o seu arquivo.txt base sera criado na pasta onde tens seus arquivos.mp4

**3.** Que os Arquivos.mp4 já foram convertidos anteriormente a criação de sua base

**4.** Que a base é alimentada sempre após seus novos arquivos serem convertidos

**5.** Que o mesmo batch verifica e faz a conversão de seus arquivos.mp4

**6.** Que o executável `FCIV.exe` está na mesma pasta do seu batch

---

```bat
rem :: entre na pasta de seus arquivos mp4 :: 
cd /d "D:\videos" 

rem :: defina o arquivo para salvar as strings MD5 de seus .mp4 :: 
set "_hash=%cd%\mp4_hash.txt"

rem :: defina o caminho para seu conversor :: 
set "_ff=%ProgramFiles%\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"


rem :: se não existir a base (1º execução) salve os MD5 :: 
if not exist "%_hash%" >"%_hash%" (
     "%~dp0fciv.exe" "D:\videos" -type *.mp4 | find/v "/" 
    )else ... ::
          rem :: se existir a base para todos os mp4 chame o label :^) passando :: 
          rem :: argumento 1 == caminho\file.mp4
          rem :: argumento 2 == caminho\base_hash == _hash=%cd%\mp4_hash.txt"
          rem :: argumento 3 == caminho\FFmpeg\exe == _ff=%ProgramFiles%\FFmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe

    )else for %%i in (*.mp4)do call :^) "%%~i" "%_hash%" "%_ff%"

:^)
rem :: quando na excução nenhum argumento for passado para o :label, dai ele ::     
rem :: vai para o final do arquivo e já parando/terminado a execução do bat  :: 
if "%~1" == "" endlocal && goto=:EOF

rem :: esse loop extrair o MD5 do arquivo em loop passado no argumento %1 :: 
for /f tokens^=1-2 %%i in ('^^^< nul "%~dp0fciv.exe" "%~f1" ^|find/v "/"

rem :: ecoando MD5 e nome para acompanhamento, também procurando na base essas strings ::
rem :: e para caso de encontrar, o arquivo ja foi convertido e restando sair do label  :: 
')do echo=%%~i "%%~j" & %__AppDir__%findstr.exe %%~i "%~2">nul && exit/b 

rem :: para casos de não ter encontrado o MD5 do mp4 em loop na sua base, o seu     :: 
rem :: conversor fara a conversão do mp4 ("%~1") e gerando um arquivo temporario,   ::
rem :: adicionando "_tmp" no nome e antes da extenção .mp4 (caminho\file+_tmp+.mp4) ::
"%~3" -hide_banner -v error -stats -i "%~1" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%~dpn1_tmp%~x1"


rem :: se o seu arquivo temporario foi criado, ele será movido já sobrescrevendo o :: 
rem :: mp4 original e imediatamente o novo MD5 sera adicionado na sua base >>"%~2" :: 
2>&1 move/y "%~dpn1_tmp%~x1" "%~1">nul && ("%~dp0fciv.exe" "%~f1" |find/v "/">>"%~2"

rem :: uma mensagem informará a conversão e alimentação do banco, e logo saindo do :label :: 
     echo=Arquivo: %~nx1 & echo\Convertido ^& MD5 adicionado na base "%~2" && exit/b

rem :: caso as ações de converter/mover o arquivo não retornem 0, o operador || vai ::
rem :: executar o timeout de 5 segundos já redirecionado para uma mensagem de erro  ::
rem :: omitindo o contador e ao finalizar esse timeout ele sai do label continuando ::
rem :: as execuções com os outro arquivos .mp4 em loop, e exibindo o erro do FFmpeg ::
    ) || %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 5 | echo=Arquivo: "%~dpnx1" Falhou!... && exit/b
```

---

Observações:

**a)** O FFmpeg (`%_ff%` linha 5 | `%~3` linha 16) serve para ilustrar/sugerir onde usar conversão

**b)** È possível ter esse resultado apenas usando o FFmpeg para obter o [MD5 de arquivos](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash)

**c)** Também é possível [adicionar](https://write.corbpie.com/adding-metadata-to-a-video-or-audio-file-with-ffmpeg/) e/ou [consultar](https://superuser.com/questions/1303106/read-only-one-tag-from-mp4-metadata) metadata `comment=Convertido` sem usar uma base

**d)** O `FCIV.exe` é indicado para uso com alguma ferramenta que manipule `arquivos.xml`

**e)** Use o [CertUtil.exe](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-md5-sha256-checksum-built-in-utility/) que já vem com sistema para obter o MD5, não precisa baixar o `FCIV.exe`

```bat
Certutil -hashfile "D:\videos\arquivo.mp4" md5|find/v "."
```

---

**Respondendo:**

- Para salvar uma variável obtendo em loop o MD5 do `FCIV.exe`:

```bat
rem :: salvando apenas o MD5 :: 
for /f %%i in ('^^^< nul "fciv.exe" "arquivo.mp4" ^|find/v "/"
')do set "_md5=%%~i"

rem :: salvando o MD5 e o nome do arquivo :: 
for /f tokens^=1* %%i in ('^^^< nul "fciv.exe" "arquivo.mp4" ^|find/v "/"
')do set "_md5_nome=%%~i %%~j"

rem :: salvando o MD5, o nome do arquivo e o caminho completo :: 
for /f tokens^=1* %%i in ('^^^< nul "fciv.exe" "%CD%\arquivo.mp4" -wb ^|find/v "/"
')do set "_md5_nome=%%~i %%~j"
```

---

- Para salvar uma variável obtendo em loop o MD5 do arquivo_base.txt:

**Obs.:** Se criado usando: **`>"arquivo_base.txt" "fciv.exe" "arquivo.mp4" ^|find/v "/"`**

```bat
rem :: salvando apenas o MD5 :: 
for /f %%i in ('type arquivo_base.txt')do set "_md5=%%~i"

rem :: salvando o MD5 e o nome do arquivo :: 
for /f tokens^=1* %%i in (''type arquivo_base.txt'')do set "_md5_nome=%%~i %%~j"

rem :: salvando o MD5, o nome do arquivo e caminho completo :: 
for /f tokens^=1* %%i in ('type arquivo_base.txt')do set "_md5_path_name=%%~i %%~j"
```

---

- Algumas leituras adicionais (`/English`):

  [√] **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[Find /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[CertUtil /?](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)**

  [√] **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.htm)**

  [√] **[Escape Characters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier /Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533)**

  [√] **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

  [√] **[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**